# PHP fgets returns an empty string

Tags: php

So I'm making a webshop, well, trying to atleast for a course project using WAMP. But when trying to register new users and in the process checking their password against a list of common ones the use of fgets() returns an empty string.

```
if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
    ...
} elseif (!checkPassword($_POST["password"])) {
    $password_err = "Password to common.";
    echo "<script>alert('Password to common.'); location.href='index.php';</script>";
}
```

The checkPassword() is where the fault lies.

```
function checkPassword($passwordtocheck) {
    $passwordtocheck = strtolower($passwordtocheck);

    $common_passwords = fopen("commonpasswords.txt", "r");

    while(!feof($common_passwords)) {
        $check_against = fgets($common_passwords);
        echo "<script>alert('Checking $passwordtocheck against $check_against.'); location.href='index.php';</script>";
        if($check_against == $passwordtocheck) {
            fclose($common_passwords);
            return false;
        }
    }
    fclose($common_passwords);
    return true;
}
```

Lets say that I input the password 12345678 when registering, then the scripted alert will say "Checking 12345678 against ." and send me back to index.php. So it looks like it doesn't succeed in reading the file at all. The commonpasswords.txt is in the same folder as the rest of the files and with a single password on each row.

And there is no problem opening the file to begin with either, if I do this instead:

```
$common_passwords = fopen("commonpasswords.txt", "a");
fwrite($common_passwords, "test");
```

'test' will appear at the bottom of the file under the existing words on its own row without a hitch. And this is where I'm at, would appreciate whatever input people can give!

EDIT; I do understand that this probably breaks a ton of good-practice 'rules' in general and regarding security. But the website is not really supposed to function or look good, it just need to barely work so that we can later try and use different methods of attacking it and the connected database.

Comment: Why are you outputting what looks like JavaScript once for every line of this file? You should just use an established library to determine password strength.

Comment: Why are you not using a database. It would actually be so much easier to do this in one simple query

Comment: If you don't want to use a library, I would suggest to use regex like this: `if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]).{6,}$/', $password){ echo "error"; } else { echo "looks ok"; }`. This will force the password to be at least 6 characters long, contain 1 upper case character, 1 number and 1 special character.

Comment: Works for me... Do you have an empty line?

Comment: @miken32 Well, I thought it was just doing it once since it will redirect me to the index page afterwards, but maybe it keeps going I dont really know. But I just put that script there to see if it got into the while-loop to begin with, which it did. It's the if statement afterwards that's not being used since the string is empty.

Comment: By default, content is only sent to the browser at completion of the script, not incrementally.  So _all_ of the Javascript will be sent to the browser _after_ the processing of all the PHP.

Comment: @msg Nope, I've checked that file plenty of times at this point ^^

Comment: @PatrickQ Oooh okay, well then I can see why that's not so good, but it wont be there in the end. Good to know though for future reference, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on doing this yourself – which I do not recommend – you can simplify things a lot by using [the `file()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). This returns an array of every line in the file. Then use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php); it runs a callback on each element of the array where you can check if there's a match with your password. If the callback returns false, the element is removed from the array. After that, if you have any elements left you know there was a match.

```
function checkPassword($pwd) {
    $pwd = strtolower($pwd);
    $common = file("commonpasswords.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $results = array_filter($common, function($i) use ($pwd) {return $i == $pwd;});
    return count($results) === 0;
}
```

But really, there are dozens of libraries out there to check password strength. Use one of them.

Or, as pointed out in the comment, even simpler `array_search`:

```
function checkPassword($pwd) {
    $pwd = strtolower($pwd);
    $common = file("commonpasswords.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    return array_search($pwd, $common) === false;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `array_filter` why not `array_search`?

Comment: Yup, that would work too. I'd just answered another question about `array_filter` so I guess it was on my mind ;)

Comment: Not doing it alone, but I realize that I'm probably breaking a good amount of good practice and security 'rules', but that's nothing that is important at this moment. Especially since the course if about security and that we're supposed to carry out some attacks on the site and database afterwards.

I will try that method you posted with array_search, it looks simple enough, that's for the help!

Comment: @miken32 So I've tried both of your suggestions, neither is working for me. I opened the txt file and in there was everything on a single row while it was on seperate rows in Atom. Though, fixing that didn't do much but making it look weird in atom with several rows between each word, and the check still not working. I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: now if I create a new file with fopen with 'w' for write only, write in "password" and then read it with file() like your second suggestion it will work if I try and register with "password" as password. But then when I try and copy the list from the commonpasswords.txt file into that new file it's not working anymore.

Comment: Make sure your file has appropriate line endings for the platform that php is running on.

Comment: My god that addition fixed it! Would love an explenation as to why that would solve it. Anyways, thanks you so much!

Comment: By default `file` returns the entire line including the CR/LF.